# Facing issue with H2 and dbms_lob

Tags: h2

IN my unit tests am using H2 database . IN real world am using Oracle.
So we have a query which runs fine in Oracle:

```
update emp.emp_data set current_state = empty_clob() 
where  dbms_lob.compare(current_state, empty_clob()) != 0
```

The error we get is :

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema "DBMS_LOB" not found; SQL statement:
update emp.emp_data set current_state = empty_clob() 
where  dbms_lob.compare(current_state, empty_clob()) != 0 [90079-224]
```

am using h2 version 2.2.224 .
any clues ?

Comment: *The case sensitivity of the path and database name depend on the operating system, however it is recommended to use lowercase letters only.* https://www.h2database.com/html/features.html

Comment: EMPTY_LOB() and DBMS_LOB.COMPARE() are Oracle-specific functions, they aren't needed in other database systems, because in them nulls are distinct from empty strings and because there are standard functions to get the length of a string. You can define your own user-defined functions with these names in H2, however.